# How do I set proxy exception for specific application?

Tags: proxy

Is is possible to use proxy server for all the application except one (Jmeter).
I searched internet and found that proxy exception can be added to host, not for application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter case, you can also manually specify a non-proxy setting:
[Jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand my question. I am not behind a firewall/proxy, I just want to use JMeter as Proxy server for all the system requests. For that I will set JMeter proxy server as default proxy for system. But If I set it as system proxy even Jmeter will use that proxy. I want jmeter to directly connect to internet while other applications connect through proxy server.

Comment: Looking again in the JMeter documentation, it's specified that you shall not use JMeter as system proxy, only in your browser(s): [Jmeter Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server)

Comment: Sorry I could not find it, which text should I search for exactly?

Comment: Quote from the page: "You also need to set up your browser to use the JMeter proxy port as the proxy for HTTP and HTTPS requests. Do not use JMeter as the proxy for any other request types - FTP, etc. - as the JMeter proxy cannot handle them."

Comment: I don't want to add it as FTP proxy. I want to add it as HTTP proxy  for system